# Custom option in product creation is not taking '0' as a value

Tags: product, magento2.2.2, customizable-options

While creating products we have customizable options. After adding the option, in the add value field if I give 0(zero) its not taking.Giving Invalid option value error message.But its taking 00.How to solve this Magento bug.

Answer (score 2):

In customizable options not taking '0'(Zero) as a value, for that you have to put one single space before '0'(Zero),because we have use '0'(Zero) as a option's title or sub option's title so we have just displaying '0'(Zero) as a title on front side, so you can put one single space before '0'(Zero).

If you have not put manually one space before '0'(Zero),then you have to done using programmatically.

1) In **DefaultValidator.php** you have to just put one condition.

> Magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Option/Validator/DefaultValidator.php

```
if ($title == '0') {
  return true;
}

protected function isValidOptionTitle($title, $storeId)
{
    if ($title == '0') {
       return true;
    }
}
```

2) You will also changes in **Value.php** for save sub option's title.

> Magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Option/Value.php

```
protected function _saveValueTitles(AbstractModel $object)
{
    $title = $object->getTitle();
    if ($title == '0') {
       $title = ' 0';
    }
}
```

Replace **$object->getTitle()** To **$title**.

3) You will also changes in **Option.php** for save main option's title.

> Magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Option.php

```
protected function _saveValueTitles(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
{
   $title = $object->getTitle();
   if ($title == '0') {
      $title = ' 0';
   }
}
```

Replace **$object->getTitle()** To **$title**.

I hope this will useful for you.:)

Comment: i have given space after '0'.its worked fine.Thank you.

Comment: Always welcome :).